# 'Audio' was used before it was defined

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, jslint, ecmascript-5

I have a JavaScript file that I'm checking with JSLint (Notepad++ plugin v0.8.2). I have the following options set:

```
/*jslint indent: 4, maxerr: 9999, white: true, browser: true, devel: true,
es5: true, plusplus: true, regexp: true, sloppy: true */
```

[image]

JSLint is complaining on this line:

```
new Audio('sounds/ding.wav').play();
```

> '`Audio`' was used before it was defined

Seems it doesn't like ES5? How can I make this error go away?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to list `Audio` as a "*Predefined*" in the plugin's options or, as you mentioned, [as a `global`](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html#global) within the file that's using it:

```
/*global Audio: false */
```

Including `false` here describes it as read-only.

The error is because JSLint [doesn't currently acknowledge it](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint/blob/a2935fbda12c4c2de57de1761d4a50c166a5b3ce/jslint.js#L340-L348) as a possible global for browsers:

```
// browser contains a set of global names that are commonly provided by a
// web browser environment.

        browser = array_to_object([
            'clearInterval', 'clearTimeout', 'document', 'event', 'FormData',
            'frames', 'history', 'Image', 'localStorage', 'location', 'name',
            'navigator', 'Option', 'parent', 'screen', 'sessionStorage',
            'setInterval', 'setTimeout', 'Storage', 'window', 'XMLHttpRequest'
        ], false),
```

Also, note that `Audio` is [defined by HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement#Specifications) rather than ECMAScript.

Comment: Yep, just fwiw, Audio's nowhere [in the source](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint/blob/master/jslint.js). Chicken dinner.